# Combining vba filters

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to combine these two lines so that when I run the code rows that contain Oranges do not appear. At the moment, only the first filter is working. So I get all of the Apples, but the second filter does not.

Thanks in advance!

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B4", Range("BT4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=24, 
Criteria1:= "Apples"

ActiveSheet.Range("B4", Range("BT4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=20, 
Criteria1:="<>Oranges", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Edit: Solution - what I needed to do was to place "*" around oranges, because I wanted to filter out anything that contained the word "Oranges".

```
With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B4", Range("BT4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter
        .Range("B4", Range("BT4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter field:=24, 
        Criteria1:="Apples"
        .Range("B4", Range("BT4").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter field:=20, 
        Criteria1:="<>*Oranges*"
End With
```

Comment: Perhaps, when you requested `Apples`, there're only `Oranges` in 20-th field.

Comment: There are lots of different fruits, but Oranges have not all been filtered out. I think it is something to do with combining the filters into one statement, I'm just not sure how to do it

Comment: Works for me. Taking note of @JonnyL's comment. You are filtering a later field first not that that makes a difference.

Comment: Works for me too. You can't combine those into a single line as they are filtering different columns.

Comment: Ok I think I know why it might work for you and not for me, not that this solves my problem. It does not get rid of all the "Oranges", but these "Oranges" are sometimes in the middle of phrases, not just by themselves. So what I am really trying to do is filter anything with "Oranges" in it out

Comment: Hey QHarr - yes I think using the "*" sorted it out. I edited my code with the solution, is there something I should do to mark it as answered?

Comment: Please post your solution EDIT as an answer to this question rather than as an edit into the question.

Comment: Then in 2 days you can accept as answer.